# How to fix the git repo if I accidentally create the repo with a submodule (sub repo) in it?

Tags: git, create-react-app, git-submodules

If I do the following:

```
mkdir TryReactHooks
cd TryReactHooks
npx create-react-app my-app
git init 
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:username/tryreacthooks.git  # optional
git add .
git commit -am "Initial Commit"
git push -u origin master
```

then for some reason, this repo doesn't seem to track any file in the `my-app` folder.  It is probably due to `my-app` is a repo by itself (because `create-react-app` did it).  If I do

```
mv my-app/.git my-app/.git-tmp
```

so that `my-app` is no longer a git repo, I find that still the current repo won't track any changes made to `my-app` even if I do `git add .`  How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I used some of those commands as an alias and didn't see one "hint" from git.

Turns out after you rename the `my-app/.git` to `my-app/.git-tmp`

Do a

```
git rm --cached my-app
```

and now you can

```
git add .
git com -am "ok"
```

and add all files to the repo.

The "hint" from git was:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> my-app
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached my-app
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Does `git status` shows the my-app directory under "**Untracked files:**"? If yes, do `git add my-app` to start tracking the changes.
2. Inspect '`.gitignore`' file and see whether the relevant directory is being ignored.
3. If you don't need the "my-app" directory to be a separate repository, try deleting the '`.git/`' directory rather than moving it.

Let me know if any of this works.

Comment: `git add .` (note the dot) in `TryReactHooks` adds nothing

Comment: Ok, so under ```git status``` does not show my-app under **Untracked-files**. What about the other two options?

Comment: there is no `.gitignore` in the top folder

Comment: removing the whole `.git` folder in `my-app` doesn't work